# Does lettrine work in vietnamese?

Tags: babel

Using

```
\selectlanguage{vietnamese}
\lettrine{Đ}{o lường}
```

does not work in texlive 2014:

```
! Missing \endcsname inserted.
<to be read again> 
                   \T5\DJ
```

Is there a way to make it work?

Comment: please post a small complete example that shows the error

Comment: If the sample document by David below throws an error, upgrade your TeX distribution.

Comment: I can compile the example in the answer below with TeX Live from 2012 to 2016 (and also 2017 pretest). Please, add a minimal example.

Answer (score 1):

I get no error from

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[vietnamese,english]{babel}
\usepackage{lettrine}

\begin{document}
\selectlanguage{vietnamese}
\lettrine{Đ}{o lường} 
zzzzzzzzzzz zzzzzzzzzzzzzz
zzzzzzzzzzz zzzzzzzzzzzzzz
zzzzzzzzzzz zzzzzzzzzzzzzz
zzzzzzzzzzz zzzzzzzzzzzzzz
zzzzzzzzzzz zzzzzzzzzzzzzz


\end{document}
```